# How to get rid of names of functions under functions in MMA 12 frontend?

Tags: version-12

How to get rid of the smaller names of functions (*sinus*, *pi* etc.) under the code? From all notebooks, automatically, forever?

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"

Comment: How did you get them to appear like that in the first place? It looks like it might have to do with language localization?

Comment: **Uncheck** `Preferences | Interface | Language Settings |Show code captions (non-English languages only)`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you!